# Node paths with custom prefix based on taxonomy

Tags: taxonomy-terms, path-aliases

I have a "category" field attached to the "article" content type that is a taxonomy term reference. I want to setup path auto to create a path wich is prefixed based on the category. My problem is that i.e.: I have a category called "Interesting facts", path auto will create a path **/interesting-facts/node-title** but I want to have **/facts/node-title** And I could change the taxonomy term to "Facts", but the taxonomy term index page would show "Facts" too, but I want it to remain "Interesting facts".

So basically I want to customize prefixes, without changing the taxonomy terms. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new field on the Category Taxonomy called something like "Title Prefix" and then use this Field to create a custom path for the article